# FactoryGirl - can't write unknown attribute, and undefined method `name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, associations, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a `photo` factory that's in a many to one association with `gallery`. And I'm getting two errors, depending on how I specify the association between those two models.

Here's the models:

**Photo**

```
belongs_to :gallery, class_name: "SevenGallery::Gallery"
```

**Gallery**

```
has_many :photos, class_name: "SevenGallery::Photo", foreign_key: "seven_gallery_gallery_id", dependent: :destroy
```

And the migrations

```
create_table :seven_gallery_galleries do |t|
 t.string :title  
   t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :seven_gallery_photos do |t|
   t.string :caption
   t.string :image
   t.references :seven_gallery_gallery, index: true
   t.timestamps null: false
 end

 add_foreign_key :seven_gallery_photos, :seven_gallery_galleries, on_delete: :cascade
```

Now Here's my factories:
**Gallery**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :gallery, class: 'SevenGallery::Gallery' do
    title "an event gallery"
    factory :gallery_with_photos do 
        after(:build) do |gallery| 
            gallery.photos << FactoryGirl.create(:photo_one, seven_gallery_gallery_id: gallery)
            gallery.photos << FactoryGirl.create(:photo_two, seven_gallery_gallery_id: gallery)
            gallery.photos << FactoryGirl.create(:photo_three, seven_gallery_gallery_id: gallery)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

And **Photo**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :photo, class: "SevenGallery::Photo" do

      factory :photo_one do
      end

      factory :photo_two do
      end

      factory :photo_three do
      end

      factory :photo_with_gallery do
        gallery 
      end
  end
end
```

And here's the controller spec that generates the error:

```
it "changes is_main to true in self and false in rest" do
    photo_one = FactoryGirl.create(:photo_with_gallery)
    expect(photo_one.gallery).to be_a SevenGallery::Gallery
end
```

Whenever I run the test I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: photo_one = FactoryGirl.create(:photo_with_gallery)
     ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute `gallery_id`
     # ./spec/controllers/seven_gallery/photos_controller_spec.rb:
```

When I change  the association part to be:

```
factory :photo_with_gallery do
  association :gallery, factory: gallery    
end
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: photo_one = FactoryGirl.create(:photo_with_gallery)
  NoMethodError:
     undefined method `name' for :photo_with_gallery:Symbol 
   # ./spec/controllers/seven_gallery/photos_controller_spec.rb:8
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150428105107) do

  create_table "seven_event_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "seven_gallery_galleries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.integer  "seven_event_event_id"
  end

  add_index "seven_gallery_galleries", ["seven_event_event_id"], name: "index_seven_gallery_galleries_on_seven_event_event_id"

  create_table "seven_gallery_photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "caption"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "seven_gallery_gallery_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
    t.boolean  "is_new",                   default: true
    t.boolean  "is_featured",              default: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "alt"
    t.integer  "position",                 default: 0
    t.boolean  "is_main",                  default: false
  end

  add_index "seven_gallery_photos", ["seven_gallery_gallery_id"], name: "index_seven_gallery_photos_on_seven_gallery_gallery_id"

end
```

**Backtrace**:

```
# /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:138:in `with_value_from_database'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:39:in `write_from_user'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:74:in `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:56:in `write_attribute'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:96:in `write_attribute'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:373:in `[]='
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:83:in `replace_keys'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:14:in `replace'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `gallery='
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `public_send'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/controllers/seven_gallery/photos_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <module:SevenGallery>'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `block in run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `block in run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:549:in `block in run_examples'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:545:in `map'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:545:in `run_examples'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `block in run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `map'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:513:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `map'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Any help would ne appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the full backtrace say? Try running your spec with `rspec -b` for a full backtrace.

Comment: @Thomas I've edited the question with the backtrace, ? please check it :)

Comment: Can you please provide your schema.rb file?

Comment: @JoeEssey I've added the `schema.rb` file in the question. Please check it.

Comment: Try changing  the definition for `factory :photo_with_gallery` to use `seven_gallery_gallery`.

Comment: @JoeEssey It gives me this error `undefined method 'name' for :photo_with_gallery:Symbol`

Comment: Maybe I'm not too smart, but this code is difficult to follow because of the use of modules.  Perhaps it is worthwhile for you to start over and get these relationships working correctly and then move to modulization if it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone facing the same problem. The solution is to include `foreign_key` in both sides: `has_many` side and `belongs_to` side.